# T-SQL get all nodes and their last level children using common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I need the last level children of all nodes between the last level and the parent. I am new to recursive ctes and trying to get this result.

Consider the following table:

```
emp id  |  mgr id
1          null
2          1
3          1
4          1
5          2
6          2
7          3
8          3
9          4
10         4
11         5
12         6
13         6
14         6
15         11
```

if the input is `(15)` then the output should be

```
mgr id     emp id
2          12
2          13
2          14
2          15
5          15
6          12
6          13
6          14
11        15
```

Searching around the web I figured this can be done using recursive queries but I am unable to.

```
with cte as
(
    select 
        emp_id, mgr_id
    from  
        emp_heirarchy
    where 
        emp_id in (select MIN(lt.emp_id) 
                   from landing_table lt
                   inner join emp_heirarchy eh on lt.emp_id = eh.emp_id
                   group by mgr_id)

    union all

    select 
        eh.emp_id, eh.mgr_id
    from  
        emp_heirarchy eh
    inner join 
        cte c on c.mgr_id = eh.emp_id
)
select distinct * 
from cte 
order by mgr_id
```

I have tried a few other versions of the above query with no luck.

Comment: Your recursive query works fine, I don't understand the expected result.

Comment: `11         16` where this 16 comes from?

Comment: I'm not understanding your desired result set. If you're traversing the hierarchy towards the managers, why stop at 2? That is, why not go up to emp_id = 1? And I second the "where did the (11, 16)" row come from?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my question and remove empid 16.

Comment: I don't want to go upto the root. I only need the in between nodes I.e. between the root and the last children. And I want each such node to be displayed with the last of their children. So we need node 2 in the result which lies between the root and the last children. The last children for node 2 are 15(from descendants 2 and 5) and 12,13,14 (from 6). Similarly I want 11, 5 and 6 to be represented in the result. I don't want anything from the other nodes because they are not related to input 15 except at the root. I don't know if it's clear now. This one's a bit difficult to explain.

Comment: please exaplin once more but use empid and mgrid while explaining.Thanks.wht is 15 (empid or mgrid) and so on..